# Which is better for a beginner, Nikon D60 or Nikon D5100?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d90, nikon-d5100

I am a bit confused on what to choose between Nikon D60 and Nikon D5100. Which one is good for a beginner or an entry level photographer?

I also see that Nikon D5100 is priced less than Nikon D60 which is an older model, why would this be? This makes me think D60 is better?

Comment: You mean D90, don't you? You have tagged the question as nikon-d90.

Comment: We have already answered similar question on D90 vs D5100 - [D5100 or D90 ? Which one to buy as the first DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13434/d5100-or-d90-which-one-to-buy-as-the-first-dslr)

Answer (score 10):

The Nikon D60 is a very old version of the D5100. The D5000 was actually between the two in the models history. **The D5100 is a step up in every important aspect**, if the price is the same, I see no reason why to get the D60 over the D5100. The D5100 is the current up to date model with great high ISO performance, a flip out screen, and other current day features.

Answer (score 0):

I, as a beginner, and after much research, chose the Nikon D5100.

I have found two separate websites ([here](http://snapsort.com/compare/Nikon-D5100-vs-Nikon_D60) and [here](http://digital-cameras.techcrunch.com/compare/340-444/Nikon-D5100-vs-Nikon-D60)) comparing the two cameras, and as a beginner, the 5100 is definitely your better option, especially in this day and age. However, later on, perhaps you will develop different preferences, and find that you enjoy the D60.

As far as functions go, the Nikon D5100 is the best of the two. As for the price question, I have no idea, maybe it's considered a classic.

Just to extend your answer.