# Did I make a mistake in choosing a D5300 rather than an older higher-end model?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d90, nikon-d5300

I recently bought D5300, initially I was happy, but after attending some photo walk sessions. I realized most people are using either D7000 or D7100 and some D90.

Now I'm confused whether I did big mistake choosing D5300 as D90 is same price as D5300. D90 seems more professional and better than D5300. I'm feeling bad about my decision.

Am I wrong?

Comment: Just buying a camera because "major people" (what does that even mean?) have the camera is not really the right approach to photography. Instead you should think in terms of what you need to do the photography you want and choose a camera that suits your needs (maybe it's not even a DSLR but a GoPro). [Here](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/417/9161) are [some](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/2876/9161) [questions](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5883/are-there-disadvantages-to-a-prosumer-camera-for-a-beginner-aside-from-cost) that might be helpful.

Comment: Use what you have until you find the point at which the D5300 is limiting you in terms of producing the shots that *you* want to do. At that point you will know *which features* you need in your next camera.

Comment: See also: [D5100 or D90? Which one to buy as the first DSLR?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13434/d5100-or-d90-which-one-to-buy-as-the-first-dslr) It's from two years ago but is still applicable in many ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you didn't make a mistake if the camera is meeting your needs.  The D90 has an advantage in terms of controls for someone who is more experienced, but the D5300 has an advantage in terms of sensor quality.  So if you are pretty new and learning, a basic model that has fewer controls to confuse can actually be an advantage for now, particularly since, all other things being equal (and assuming you don't need to be able to adjust the settings quickly), it is capable of better looking photos (just a bit harder to use in the hands of an experienced user.)

Eventually you will find the lack of controls limiting, but at that point, you will understand what you are missing because you'll be looking for it and a camera with more advanced controls will be a help rather than a hindrance.  (Also, note that you can adjust pretty much all the same settings, it is just that you have to go through menus for some things that are on direct controls on higher end models.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think you are right for me and for now I should more concentrate on clicking picture and learning it.